# Using iframe with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In my code I have a jquery script which has a next & previous page function. The jquery script loads a php script to parse a selected page. The parsed page has a div removed with the name postsArea and is placed into a div with an id of wrap. As of the moment the jQuery script is set up to put the div postsArea into the div wrap. What I want to do is put the div postsArea into a iframe with the id news.

**JQuery :**

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var $wrap = $('#wrap'),
    page = 1;
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        getPage(++page);
    });
    $('#prev').on('click', function () {
        getPage(--page);
    });
    var getPage = function (page) {
        $wrap.load('proxy.php?page=' + page + ' #postsArea');
    };
    getPage(page);
});
```

---

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html=file_get_html( 'http://roosterteeth.com/home.php?page=' . $_GET["page"]);
    echo $html;
?>
```

---

**HTML :**

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
</div>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
<button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
</body>
```

---

I really appreciate any help and thank you for your time.

Comment: is the iframe on the same domain as your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe is basically just a subwindow which is able to perform http queries. You just have to set the "src" attribute of your iframe element value to the right url.

```
$("iframe").attr("src",'proxy.php?page=' + page + ' #postsArea');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have one problem. The iframe is displaying the whole webpage and is just scrolling down to '#postsArea'. I just want to display '#postsArea' only. I hope you can help.

Comment: This involves scraping the page you are querying. You could do it server-side in proxy.php or client-side using jQuery in an ajax request (but the iframe won't be of much use there since it's suited for displaying a complete html page, not just a single element).

Comment: Could I echo 'wrap' in the iframe?